# Knowledge Graph (Demo) UI using sigma.js?

Tags: graph, data-visualization, sigma.js

Are there any beginner-friendly tutorials to display graphs in the way Knowledge graph has been done?

I have the data is JSON format presented from a graphdb

For eg:
[image: Knowledge Graph UI (demo)]

Comment: Found anything interesting ? I'm also looking for knowledge graph libraries that would produce something similar to your screenshot.

Comment: Not really. I deferred the whole thing to a later date. #procrastination

Answer (score 1):

The closest I have found so far is Gelphi. Which also can be integrated with unity to produce a 3d Graph like this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_arRCf73Kg.

Then there is https://cayley.io/

https://n0where.net/opengraphiti-data-visualization-engine/

There is also https://www.maana.io/knowledge-platform/platform-capabilities/#maana-knowledge-graph . However, i have not tried to use/download their platform.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Force-directed_graph_drawing

Finally, I am working myself on learning unity to build a simple GUI which a user can identify nodes and edges and entities easily and move them around. So instead of just reading from a data base, also write to it through a UI.